# Select Attribute from PARSE function pulling data from nested and escaped JSON

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a deep nested JSON that contains both escaped and non-escaped data. The raw response is escaped with " characters
I am trying to get the values for "requestId" but its returning NULLs no matter what I do. Here is a snippit of the JSON data. I can query and parse the data at the "RawResponse" node, but when I go into the RawResponse and try to pull requestID I get NULL.

Is there perhaps a need to do some kind of sub query against the result of the parsed function for RawResponse? Just getting started with JSON queries so any help would be truly appreciated.

```
"RawResponse": "{\"success\":true,\"requestId\":\"rrt-04a6b53f6c9c2db7d-c-wo-17410-5591259-1\",\"comments\":\"\",\"results\":
```

```
SELECT
CREDIT_ATTRIBUTES_RAW:BusinessData.AccountID::string as "AccountID",
CREDIT_ATTRIBUTES_RAW:TransactionData.ApplicationId::string as "ApplicationID",
PARSE_JSON(CREDIT_ATTRIBUTES_RAW:Report.CreditPremier.RawResponse.requestId::string) as "Premier"
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Your JSON is double-escaped (JSON within JSON). You need to double-parse it. You need to extract the value of `RawResponse` (which is a string), parse that as JSON *again*, and then you will get access to the `requestId`.

Answer (score 2):

I trimmed down your json data to test out and below is sql which helps you to drive and pull  needed columns:

```
select try_parse_json('{\"success\":true,\"requestId\":\"rrt-04a6b53f6c9c2db7d-c-wo-17410-5591259-1\"}') as t1, t1:requestId;
```

[image]